# TryCatch and names Error when running doRedis examples from documentation

Tags: r, parallel-processing, redis, cluster-computing, r-doredis

I am trying to use doRedis to create an R cluster and parallel process some of my calculations with foreach, but keep running into errors. My code works with foreach %do% but when I try to run on the cluster with %dopar% it fails. I also tried running the example code in the doRedis docs which fails as well. Below is the R console of my main script and a worker:

The main R console:

```
> require('doRedis')
> registerDoRedis('work')
> getDoParWorkers()
[1] 2
> foreach(j=1:10,.combine=sum,.multicombine=TRUE) %dopar%
+ 4*sum((runif(1000000)^2 + runif(1000000)^2)<1)/10000000
[1] "interrupt: \n"
Error in tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]]) : 
  attempt to apply non-function
In addition: Warning message:
In e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) :
  Queue length off by 10...correcting
```

The worker console:

```
> require('doRedis')
> redisWorker('work')
Waiting for doRedis jobs.
Processing job  3  from queue  work 
Error in names(z) <- w[o] : 
  'names' attribute [69] must be the same length as the vector [68]
```

I am not sure what is causing the errors but it seems like everything I send to the worker results in this error:

```
`Error in names(z) <- w[o] : 
   'names' attribute [69] must be the same length as the vector [68]`
```

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your example is that you're not using curly-braces around the body of the foreach loop. Because `%dopar%` and `%do%` are binary operators, you need to be sure that the entire body of the foreach loop is treated as the right argument to the `%dopar%` operator. In your case, the body of the foreach loop is simply `4`. By using curly-braces (or parentheses), you can fix that problem:

```
foreach(j=1:10,.combine=sum,.multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {
  4*sum((runif(1000000)^2 + runif(1000000)^2)<1)/10000000
}
```

But the real problem appears to occur when the redis worker calls the `redisInfo` function to determine the version of the redis server. I think there's an error in `redisInfo` when the "INFO" output from the server is parsed which causes the worker to fail. My guess is that when you installed a different redis server, it changed the "INFO" output which no longer triggered the bug in redisInfo, thus "fixing" the problem. Hopefully the `redisInfo` function can be improved so that this error doesn't occur again.

Comment: I tired it with the {} but still get the same error:                    Error in names(z) <- w[o] : 
  'names' attribute [69] must be the same length as the vector [68]

Comment: @NathanWadhwani It's possible that the problem is caused by a bug in doRedis. What version of doRedis and rredis are you using?

Comment: doRedis:1.1.1 and rredis:1.6.8. I installed redis on a mac with brew and think that was the issue. I think I fixed it by installing redis on a osx without brew and setting the timeout to 0 in the redis config file.

Comment: This is very likely the cause of the problem. It has been reported and some patch has been proposed: https://github.com/bwlewis/doRedis/issues/10 I was not able to compile it though

Comment: **This seems to be fixed in newly released rredis 1.6.9.** (Probably includes the mentioned patch so [custom builds](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25845523/684229) are no longer needed.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue. I used brew to install redis-server. I reinstalled redis-server without brew and set timeout to 0 in the config file. Now when I run a job the workers output:

```
`Waiting for doRedis jobs.
 Processing job  3  from queue  works 
 Processing task 10 ... from queue works jobID 3 
 Processing job  3  from queue  works 
 Processing task 100 ... from queue works jobID 3 
 Processing job  3  from queue  works 
 Processing task 13 ... from queue works jobID 3 
 Processing job  3  from queue  works 
 Processing task 14 ... from queue works jobID 3 
 Processing job  3  from queue  works 
 Processing task 16 ... from queue works jobID 3 
 Processing job  3  from queue  works 
 Processing task 18 ... from queue works jobID 3 
 Processing job  3  from queue  works 
 Processing task 2 ... from queue works jobID 3 
 Processing job  3  from queue  works 
 Processing task 21 ... from queue works jobID 3 
 [1] "Empty"`
```

I get back an empty string but I think that is because there is an error with the way I have written my function and passing it to foreach.