# How to build R package from GitHub?

Tags: r, github

I try to build [fork of R package](https://github.com/patcpsc/rredis) from github (this fork has a [fresh bugfix](https://github.com/bwlewis/doRedis/issues/10)). I am able to *build AND install* the package from github:

```
require(devtools)
install_github("patcpsc/rredis", build_vignettes = FALSE)
```

However, this doesn't produce installable package - or does it? I need to install this package on 15 machines so I prefer to build the package once and then copy and install it on the other  machines.

I tried to look for funciton like `build_github`, unfortunatelly there is none. How do I do it?

Comment: Clone the repo, then use `build()` (optionally with binary = TRUE) to build an OS-specific package

Comment: @hadley thanks. What you mean with "clone the repo"? Downloading the source? How do I do it?

Comment: If you go to the GitHub page you can see two buttons on the right.

Answer (score 5):

github has help documentation on how to [fork a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo). It sounds like you've done the first part.  Now you just need to clone the repository.  That means taking a copy for your local machine so you can work on it.  The buttons you want are on the right.  Clone in desktop is for when you use the [Github desktop software](https://windows.github.com/).  If you are running git from a command line, type

```
git clone git@github.com:whatever-the-link-is-in-the-SSH-clone-url-textbox
```

[image: github cloning screenshot]

Once you have a local copy of the repository, in R you do

```
library(devtools)
build("path/to/package/root")
```

---

I thought you wanted to actually work on the package.  If you just want to download the source, there's a "Download ZIP" button right underneath the clone options.  Download, unzip, then build in R as above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the `install_github` function is able to somehow download the source even without installing any special GitHub desktop SW. I guess there an easier way in R?

Answer (score 1):

It's old question and a lot changes since 2014. Now the workhorse is [remotes package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=remotes).

If you want installable package there is one created in your temp directory.

I usually don't want install so I create temporary library:

```
dir.create(tmp_lib <- "tmp_lib")
.libPaths(c(tmp_lib,.libPaths()))
.libPaths()
```

But you can skip that if not needed, now standard:

```
require(devtools)
install_github("patcpsc/rredis", build_vignettes = FALSE)
```

Now navigate to your temp location given by `tempdir()` (in Windows shortcut is: `shell.exec(tempdir())`).
You should see folder [fileXXXXXXXX] which should contain rredis_1.6.9.tar.gz file. This is what you need.

`unlink(tmp_lib, recursive=TRUE)` cleanup your temp directory.